# Java check Array elements duplication exists without using loops?

Tags: java, loops, collections

I have made a pair word detector, which gives me an output of `true` or `false`.
If the value in the string array contains the same string letter (duplication) will return `true`.
I used below code using nested loops
Now, I want to do the same concept without the usage of any loops?
How can I do this, any examples or what type of `java collection framework` is needed?
Thank you

Main:

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                     
    String[] box = {"Monkey","Lion","Elephant","Zebra","Tiger", "Hippo"};                                       
    String[] box2 = {"Shop","Biscuit","Cake","Cake"};                                       
    String[] box3 = {"Entrance","Gate","Price","Door","Gate"};
    String[] box4 = {"Female","Male"};                                      
    System.out.println(Pairfinder.test(box));        //false                                
    System.out.println(Pairfinder.test(box2));       //true                                 
    System.out.println(Pairfinder.test(box3));       //true  
    System.out.println(Pairfinder.test(box4));       //false                            
  }                                     
}
```

Sub:

```
public class Pairfinder                                     
{                                       
  public static boolean test(String[] value)                                        
  {                                     
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {                                        
            for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {                                        
                if (value[i].equals(value[j]) && i != j) {                                      
                    return true;                                        
                }                                       
            }                                       
        }                                       
        return false;                                       
    }                                       
}
```

Comment: Without loops? Do you mean with lambda expression? You have to iterate in some way over the array to find duplicates.

Comment: You could try inserting all the items into a Set (which doesn't allow duplicates) - if the set is smaller than the array then you have duplicates.

Comment: ^ That would work but the Set would be using loops behind the scenes.

Comment: You can use a stream. Use Arrays.stream and collect them to a map grouped by the value itself. Then do a downstream filter fit those where the count is greater than 1. If the result has at least 1 entry then there was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Streams with a one liner:

```
public static boolean test(String[] value) {
    return Arrays.stream(value).anyMatch(v -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(value), v) > 1);
}
```

But that is probably not the most performant solution, because it has a time complexity of O(n²).

Alternatively you can use a `distinct()`:

```
public static boolean test(String[] value) {
    return Arrays.stream(value).distinct().count() < value.length;
}
```

If you want to get the duplicate values you can combine both methods:

```
public static String[] getDuplicates(String[] value) {
    return Arrays.stream(value)
            .filter(v -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(value), v) > 1)
            .distinct()
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

This version also has a time complexity of O(n²) because of the `frequency()` count. A better solution would be:

```
public static String[] getDuplicates(String[] value) {
    return Arrays.stream(value)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: The `distinct` solution is the best one here. The sets (other answers) are clear but the `distinct` one is just as readable as the sets. The `anyMatch` version is clever but it makes me have to think ;-)

Comment: The `anyMatch` solution is horrible, as it will search the entire array for each array element, also known as “quadratic time complexity”. The `distinct()` variant is not bad, but still looks like an overuse of the Stream API, a good old `return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(value)).size() == value.length;` would do too. The `getDuplicates` variant doing `frequency` for every element again, will again lead to quadratic time complexity. You can use `.collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),counting())) .entrySet().stream() .filter(e -> e.getValue()>1) .map(e -> e.getKey) .toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: Thanks @Holger I already noticed the time complexity with `frequency()` but I didn't mention it that clear in my answer. I updated it and added the other example for finding the duplicates.

Comment: @Holger Oh, just copied it and forgot to remove that part :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example for your cause

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] box = {"Monkey", "Lion", "Elephant", "Zebra", "Tiger", "Hippo"};
    String[] box2 = {"Shop", "Biscuit", "Cake", "Cake"};
    String[] box3 = {"Entrance", "Gate", "Price", "Door", "Gate"};
    String[] box4 = {"Female", "Male"};
    System.out.println(checkIt(box));        //false                                
    System.out.println(checkIt(box2));       //true                                 
    System.out.println(checkIt(box3));       //true  
    System.out.println(checkIt(box4));           //false   

}

public static boolean checkIt(String[] text) {
    return !Arrays.stream(text).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

Comment: Another clever solution that I have to think about :-) I still like the `distinct` one by @SamuelPhilipp but great to see so many different approaches that all work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using `HashSet` in time complexity O(n)
*The idea is that*
Put all items in a `HashSet`
If the `array` contains duplicate values
The length of `HashSet` will not equal the length of `array`
Because **add function** of `HashSet` will add the specified element to this set if it is not already present

```
public static boolean test(String[] value) {
    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(value));
    return (value.length != hashSet.size());
}
```

Comment: To better hide the loop why not `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(value));` ?